# How to find all triples from pairs in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Assume that I use SQLite query syntax.

I have a table of distances between points:

```
CREATE TABLE d (
    p1 INT,
    p2 INT,
    distance REAL
);
```

If I know distance between `p1` and `p2` then I known distance between `p2` and `p1` - both rows are in table.

I want to create a view (`select` query) for all unique triples of points, so that I know the distances between all three of them pairwise.

I tried the following:

```
CREATE VIEW triple as
    select d1.p1 as p1, d2.p1 as p2, d3.p1 as p3
    from d as d1, d as d2, d as d3
    where d1.p1=d3.p2 and d1.p2=d2.p1 and d2.p2=d3.p1;
```

But I don't know how to get rid of transpositions like:

```
1 | 2 | 3
2 | 3 | 1
3 | 1 | 2
```

What is a fast and correct `select` query for my view?

Comment: Try this: `WHERE d1.p1 < d2.p1 AND d2.p1 < d3.p1`

Answer (score 2):

If you have *all* pairs, you can use pair-wise comparisons.  Here is one method:

```
CREATE VIEW triple as
    select d1.p1 as p1, d2.p1 as p2, d3.p1 as p3
    from d d1 join
         d d2
         on d1.p2 = d2.p1 join
         d as d3
         on d1.p1 = d3.p2 and d2.p2 = d3.p1
    where d1.p1 < d1.p2 and d3.p1 < d3.p2;
```

Comment: I don't have all pairs - the point of my view is to find all triples of points that I have pairs for, pairwise. But I'm trying to figure out if your solution will work for my situation too.